# Contact us form: Mail not received

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to create a contact us form with PHP. The problem is that, I'm not receiving the email in my account. When the submit button is clicked it takes me to the mail.php page where a "thank you" message is shown.
The code is as shown below:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-sm-8">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-6" for="email">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name*" name="fname" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="last Name" name="lname" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email ID:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address*" name="email" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message*" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The code for mail.php:

```php
<?php 
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $fname $lname \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "rubeena.ajeed@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to send email from local machine ?

Comment: sorry, i dint understand, as in?

Comment: where is this code in server or on your local computer ?

Comment: it's on the server. I have actually hosted the page and was trying the same from the hosted page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using SMTP ?

PHPmailler.class

Download : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer